# TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I solve the problem from Stepik:

> One tree is good, but where are the guarantees that it is the best, or
> at least close to it? One of the ways to find a more or less optimal
> set of tree parameters is to iterate over a set of trees with
> different parameters and choose the appropriate one. For this purpose,
> there is a GridSearchCV class that iterates over each of the
> combinations of parameters among those specified for the model, trains
> it on the data and performs cross-validation. After that, the model
> with the best parameters is stored in the .best_estimator_ attribute.
> Now the task is to iterate over all the trees on the iris data
> according to the following parameters: maximum depth - from 1 to 10
> levels the minimum number of samples for separation is from 2 to 10
> minimum number of samples per sheet - from 1 to 10 and store the best
> tree in the variable best_tree. Name the variable with GridSearchCV
> search.
> Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

parameters = {'max_depth': range(1, 10), 'min_samples_split': range(2, 10), 'min_samples_leaf': range(1, 10)}
search = GridSearchCV(iris, parameters)

search.fit(X, y)

best_tree = search.estimator
```

Why am I getting this error?:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 22, in <module>
    search.fit(X, y)
  File "/home/stepic/instances/master-plugins/sandbox/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 595, in fit
    self.estimator, scoring=self.scoring)
  File "/home/stepic/instances/master-plugins/sandbox/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py", line 342, in _check_multimetric_scoring
    scorers = {"score": check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)}
  File "/home/stepic/instances/master-plugins/sandbox/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py", line 274, in check_scoring
    "'fit' method, %r was passed" % estimator)
TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, {'data': array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
       [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
       [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
       ...
```

Comment: Typo at `GridSearchCV(iris, ...)`. You need to put an estimator (i.e. `DecisionTreeClassifier`) not the data itself (`iris`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the dataset instead of an estimator. If you haven't already, take a look at this
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

parameters = {'max_depth': range(1, 10), 'min_samples_split': range(2, 10), 'min_samples_leaf': range(1, 10)}
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                      param_grid=parameters)

search.fit(X, y)

search.cv_results_
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven passed any estimator to your GridSearchCV function. You must pass an instance of the estimator you want to fit to GridSearCV, however you are just passing iris which is not an estimator